# JavaScript - get value from multiple inputs in an array

Tags: javascript, input

I am trying to get the value from muliple inputs with the same id in an array.
I already used the forum, but haven't find a solution for me.

Exmaple

```
<input type="hidden" value="'+image_url+'" name="webcampics[]" id="webcampics">
<input type="hidden" value="'+image_url+'" name="webcampics[]" id="webcampics">
<input type="hidden" value="'+image_url+'" name="webcampics[]" id="webcampics">
<input type="hidden" value="'+image_url+'" name="webcampics[]" id="webcampics">


  var elem = document.getElementById("webcampics");
  var names = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; ++ i) {
     names += elem[i]+'|';
  }
  var webcamval = names;
```

Comment: `This attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Global_attributes

Comment: HTML does not allow two elements with the same id.  When you do include them, the results are unpredictable.  Often the problems show up when you try to search by id.  Can you give them different ids, or search by other criteria?

Comment: Sorry if forget something, I updated my answer.

Comment: @ScottSauyet The results are actually very predictable -- the browser or JavaScript engine will stop at the first ID match it finds and ignore any that come after.

Comment: @Blazemonger: How about CSS engines?  How about attribute selectors [id=xyz]?  The trouble is that you're doing something against the rules, and now you can't count on the remaining rules to work consistently.

Comment: I have done EXACTLY what you have asked for, check my answer with a fiddle included

Comment: @ScottSauyet Same thing for CSS. Attribute selectors are different; only if the JavaScript function is treating it as an attribute instead of a (presumably) unique ID will you get multiple matches. I'm not saying you SHOULD do it, just that the (undesirable) results can be predicted.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Not true in CSS:  http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/5bmEh/.  Elements are tested against selectors, so if they match the id selector, it's fine, regardless of whether there are multiple elements with that id.  I think this is why multiple copies of ids have proliferated in web development.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I stand corrected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't have elements with identical *id's* within the document. `ID`'s have to be unique throughout your entire markup, by specification. If you do it anyways, methods like `document.getElementById` will only match the very first occurence for instance.

Use a `class` instead of `ids`.

```
<input type="hidden" value="'+image_url+'" name="webcampics[]" class="webcampics">
<input type="hidden" value="'+image_url+'" name="webcampics[]" class="webcampics">
<input type="hidden" value="'+image_url+'" name="webcampics[]" class="webcampics">
<input type="hidden" value="'+image_url+'" name="webcampics[]" class="webcampics">

var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName( 'webcampics' ),
    names  = [].map.call(inputs, function( input ) {
        return input.value;
    }).join( '|' );
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/QgJrq/

Comment: How would the soultion be if I use a class for example.

Comment: Actually you CAN have ID duplicates in the DOM. It is allowed but not standard compliant.

Comment: @HamadaBadran: no its actually correct. But if you're using some legacy / old'ish browsers it might not be supported. If thats the case, replaced it with `.getElementsByTagNames( 'input' )` instead for instance. That would just grab any `input` node (which probably should be more precise in real-world apps)

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for is wrong very wrong, it is recommended IDs should be unqiue, but for learners sake here's what you would do

```
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var names = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; ++i) {
    if (typeof elem[i].attributes.id !== "undefined") {
      if (elem[i].attributes.id.value == "webcampics") {
        names.push(elem[i].value);
      }
    }
  }
  var webcamval = names;
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/5vamG/

Due to someone down voting after giving a full explanation why the above mentioned method is wrong, however does exactly what youve asked for, here's the correct method.

change all the inputs id to class

```
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("webcampics");
  var names = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; ++i) {
    if (typeof elem[i].value !== "undefined") {
        names.push(elem[i].value);
      }
    }
  }
  var webcamval = names;
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/5vamG/1/

Comment: although this is a bad thing, as ID's should be unique it does specifically what you asked for

Comment: Don't encourage new programmers to embrace bad practices with kludgey code. Teach them the right practices instead.

Comment: Try reading what i have put before the script?... what they are  asking for is WRONG, i gave a script which specified their needs for the sake of teaching how it can be done. the downvote was really unnecessary, please read my entire post rather than the quoted script :@

Comment: I know exactly what you were doing. It shouldn't be done anyway. Please don't teach new programmers bad habits.

Comment: I AM A NEW PROGRAMMER, if i just give the right method there's no flexibility in the way they learn to program, I can't remember saying use my method alternatively to the correct methods provided

Comment: sorry for getting a bit :/, I am a new programmer and i appreciate being given the valid methods as well as the way it was asked for, for me to learn alternative methods

Answer (score 2):

1. You shouldn't have more than one element with the same `id`.
2. `getElementById` returns exactly one element; use `getElementsByName` which will return the list you seek.