# How to get multidimensional array from an array of inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, multidimensional-array

I have the following setup:

```
<input name="myInput[3][0]" type="text">
<input name="myInput[3][1]" type="text">
<input name="myInput[4][0]" type="text">
<input name="myInput[4][1]" type="text">
```

With php it is pretty easy to access the values after the form has been submitted. For example using a "post"-method the values of the inputs are stored in the multidimensional array `$_POST['myInput']`. Then the first element in each dimension can be accessed with `$_POST['myInput'][3][0]`.

Is there a similar functionality in JavaScript that can be used even without submitting a form via the "post"-method?

Following [JavaScript - get value from multiple inputs in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321862/javascript-get-value-from-multiple-inputs-in-an-array), I added a class called "myInput" to each `input`-element, like

```
<input name="myInput[3][0]" type="text" class="myInput">
```

Then I tried this:

```
var myInput= document.getElementsByClassName('myInput');
```

But, unsurprisingly, this gives me only a 1-dimensional array not respecting any of the array keys. So not exactly the result sought for. (Also it seems odd to fiddle around with classes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the example you provided, you can use 'match' function on the name of the input to get the indexed

```
m = inputs[i].name.match(/\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]/);
```

A full working example is made available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QgJrq/151/)  (jsfiddle)

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName( 'webcampics' ),
res  = {}, i;
for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){

    m = inputs[i].name.match(/\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]/);
   if(!res[m[1]]){
       res[m[1]] = {};
    }
   res[m[1]][m[2] ]= inputs[i].value;

  }

 console.log(res);
```

As to using class as selector. If JQuery is used, an alternative is to wrap all input elements inside a div or form, give it an id (e.g. 'my_inputs'), then you can get the inputs like this:

```
var inputs = $('#my_inputs input');
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work. However, as I mentioned in my post, I am still unsatisfied with the selection of the elements by class, since this seems to ruin the easiness of styling the the input-elements with css. Whenever I change the class I will have to check for both the css style and the JavaScript evaluation. This cannot really be the standard way to do this. Is there a way to select all the input elements only by using the names or so?

Comment: You can have multiple classes on an element. You can use one for as selector and the rest for styling. Using classes as selectors is very common, I don't think it is odd.

Comment: Maybe it is just because I am only used to using classes for css. It just seems strange to have this double naming: one for the name and one for the class, while all the information seems to be accessible already from the name alone.

Comment: Hi, if you use JQuery, there are handy ways to select the input elements without using 'class' (see my updated answer). Otherwise, using class is the easiest with pure JavaScript.

Comment: Okay, I guess you mean to wrap everything in a another element, e.g. a `div` with `id="my_inputs"`.