# How to get a input value from dynamic list

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I don't know how to get the value, with js always show me the first input value! Thanks in advance!!!

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
while($i < $forid){
?>
<div id="mydiv">
    <input type="text" id="myid" name="myid" value="<?php echo $arrayid[$i]; ?>">
    <input type="text" id="myname" name="myname" value="<?php echo $arrayname[$i];?>">
    <input type="text" id="myjob"name="myjob" value="<?php echo $arrayjob[$i]; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="get values" id="getvaluesbutton">
</div>  
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you describe your problem more precisely?

Comment: Where is your JavaScript?

Comment: Also you should replace ids of your elements by classes names

Comment: when i get the values with js "byid" , allways i get  the first value of different arrays in position $i = 0 .

Comment: you have duplicate `id` as 'myid' and ...

Comment: What's the value you don't know how to get? You need more explanation in your question

Comment: sorry, onclick button execute showmevalues();

Comment: <script>
function showvalues() {
  var value1= document.getElementById("myid").value;
  var value2= document.getElementById("myname").value;
  var value3= document.getElementById("myjob").value;
}
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get array access to elements by class/name in your js script by changing html:

```
<?php 
while($i < $forid){
?>
<div id="mydiv">
    <input type="text" name="myid[]" class="myid" value="<?php echo $arrayid[$i]; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="myname[]" class="myname" value="<?php echo $arrayname[$i];?>">
    <input type="text" name="myjob[]" class="myjob" value="<?php echo $arrayjob[$i]; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="get values" id="getvaluesbutton">
</div>  
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

for javascript hints read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321862/javascript-get-value-from-multiple-inputs-in-an-array)